# How do I find the interval of concavity for this function?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

So I've got this function:

$$F=\frac{x}{(x^2+r^2)^{3/2}}$$

When I graph $F$ against $x$ and set $r$ as an arbitrary number, it very clearly has an interval of convergence, however derivating and setting $F$ as 0 only gives an interval at $x$ equals 0. How do I find the other one?

Comment: you must compute the second derivative of F(x)

Answer (score 0):

For a function that is differentiable twice, $f$ is concave in  $(a,b)$ if $f''<0$.

Let us calculate:

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{(x^2+r^2)^{\frac32}}\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{(x^2+r^2)^{\frac32} - x \cdot 2x\cdot \frac{3}{2} {(x^2+r^2)^{\frac12}}}{(x^2+r^2)^3}=$$

$$\frac{(x^2+r^2) - x \cdot 2x\cdot \frac{3}{2} }{(x^2+r^2)^\frac52} = \frac{-2x^2+r^2}{(x^2+r^2)^\frac52}$$
Deriving again will give us

$$ f''(x) = (6x^2-9r^2) \cdot \frac{x}{(x^2+r^2)^\frac72} < 0 $$

The denominator is always positive, so it doesn't affect the sign of $f''$.

We are left with

$$ x \cdot (6x^2 - 9r^2) < 0$$
And solving this will give you the intervals in which the function is concave. I will leave you to do the rest :)